# using RSPython in MacOSX

Tags: python, r, installation

I am trying to install the
[R/SPlus - Python Interface (RSPython)](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPython/) on my Mac OS X 10.4.11 with R version 2.7.2 (2008-08-25) and python 2.6.2 from fink.

The routine:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL -c RSPython_0.7-1.tar.gz
```

produced this error message:

```
* Installing to library '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library'
* Installing *source* package 'RSPython' ...
checking for python... /sw/bin/python
Python version 2.6
Using threads
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RSPython'
** Removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/library/RSPython'
```

The config.log was not created o my system.

The contact e-mail address to the author does not work anymore, so I just hope somebody here tried the same already or can give me an alternative for running R routines in python.

Best regards,

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Try running R CMD CHECK RSPython_0.7-1.tar.gz
That should produce at least produce bunch of logs in a RSPython.Rcheck folder

You might get some clues in there.

Update --- 
If you can get one of the other packages to work I'd recommend it.  On my system (R 2.9.1 using system python (2.6) in /usr/bin/python), install works but then RSPython fails to run due to problems inside its .First.lib function. I expect you would need to hack the sources considerably to get it to work.

Comment: thanks, maybe I can use this knowledge during future installations. In the meantime  I started using rpy2 and (until now) it looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

To debug this, simply unpack the tar file yourself (`tar xzvf RSPython_0.7-1.tar.gz`) and run `./configure` in the directory created. You should get a config.log file that you can examine.

Comment: thanks a lot! Yes, I should have done it that way.  
But I started using rpy2 and (until now) it looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [rpy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) and [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) packages and going to try those as an alternative to the older RSPython.

rpy2 is includes in fink's unstable distribution ... well, and it just works fine.

Comment: Since rpy and rpy2 don't provide R -> python communication, I presume you were just looking from python -> R communication in the first place. Why did you choose the R package then, instead of a python package?